# if (+window.location.pathname+ != siteurl)

Tags: jquery

I have this function witch works fine but i have to make it right.
sometimes if am in an blog article i want to match the url. if is not = a want ro redirect to home.

i have:

```
function home() {
    $('#container').slideUp(1000); $('#container').slideDown(1000);
    $('#home').slideDown(1000);
    $('#contact').slideUp(1000);
    $('#about').slideUp(1000);
    $('#lado').slideUp(1000);
}
```

I think it should look something like this:

```
var siteurl = "http://www.site.com/"
function home() {
  if (+window.location.pathname+ != siteurl) {
    redirect to siteurl
  } else {
    $('#container').slideUp(1000); $('#container').slideDown(1000);
    $('#mail_response').slideUp(1000);
    $('#home').slideDown(1000);
    $('#contact').slideUp(1000);
    $('#about').slideUp(1000);
    $('#lado').slideUp(1000);
  };
});
```

thank you in advance.
@l3ny

Answer (score 0):

```
if (location.host != 'www.site.com'){
   location = 'http://www.site.com/';
}else{
   ...
}
```

(And you have a superfluous right paren at the end of your proposed function.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var siteurl = "http://www.site.com/"
function home() {
  if (window.location.href != siteurl) {
    redirect to siteurl
  } else {
    $('#container').slideUp(1000); $('#container').slideDown(1000);
    $('#mail_response').slideUp(1000);
    $('#home').slideDown(1000);
    $('#contact').slideUp(1000);
    $('#about').slideUp(1000);
    $('#lado').slideUp(1000);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes thank you very much,  just to be precise this dis it:

var siteurl = "http://www.site.com/"
function home() {
  if (window.location.href != siteurl) {
    window.location = "www.site.com";
}else{
   ...
}

Thank you Phrogz.

@l3ny